# How to create a game app in Game Maker Studio for Chrome OS

Tags: game-maker, game-maker-studio-2

There are multiple app types in Game Maker Studio you can export to. Which one would be for a Chromebook? I've tried to research the topic, but I haven't seen anything that clearly states if GMS can even create a game for use on a Chromebook. It seems there may be a lack of communication between me and the search engine, depending on if I know the correct terms for what I'm trying to look for. For example, there's macOS, Windows, iOS, etc. But I don't see Chrome OS or anything. What would be compatible with a Chromebook?

Comment: Don't Chromebooks run on Android?

Comment: it says officially that they run on "google chrome os" but i dont know much about it and if it can run anroid apps.

Comment: it seems chrome os can run andriod apps with emulation, but I'm not sure its run a game maker game without something like google play

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome OS devices [run on top of Gentoo Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chrome_OS), but Google officially supports the installation of [Android apps on Chromebooks](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/7021273). This means that you can install apps from the Play Store or sideload them from an external source.

Then, you can export your GMS project to Android. Your game should support both touch and mouse/keyboard input so that it'll work on most Chromebooks.

Once your `.apk` file is ready, you can install and use **ADB** on your Chrome OS device to install your game. If unsure about how to do it, you can find several guides, such as [this one](https://beebom.com/how-sideload-android-apps-chromebook/).

---

**EDIT**
Apparently, in the Player settings, *Configuration* section under the *Other Settings* pane, you can choose whether your `.apk` shall run on any Android-based OS, only on mobiles/TVs, or only on Chrome OS devices. Also, an additional option for Chrome OS input simulation is available:

[image: Player settings]

This may help you when developing a game for Chrome OS-only that you don't want to work on other Android devices instead.